# Multiple form with same form-name. But I want to send that form value that is being selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

In my website, I am retrieving multiple previously saved addresses from the database and showing them on my website. Now, the user can select any one of them and the data of the address selected will be send to the next page to be inserted into the database.

http://tinypic.com/r/2lj70i9/5

My jsp code to fetch address:

```
<a href="javascript:next()">
<div class="address1">
<form name="form2" method="post">
<input name="name" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<% out.print(x1); %>" style="font-weight: bold;" />
<input name="address" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<% out.print(x2);%>"/>
<input name="city" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<% out.print(rs1.getString("city"));%>"/>
<input name="state" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<% out.print(rs1.getString("state"));%>"/>
<input name="pin" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<% out.print(rs1.getString("pin"));%>"/>
<input name="phone" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<% out.print(rs1.getString("mob"));%>"/>
</form>
<div class="selectLine">Click to Select</div>
</div>
</a>
```

and my Javascript is:

```
function next()
{
var f=document.forms["form2"];
f.method="post";
f.action='checkout3.jsp';
f.submit();
}
```

but the problem is whatever I'm selecting only the top address is being fetched to the next page.

Comment: Have you considered having unique names for your forms? Then it should submit the right form when submitting.

Comment: the form values are dynamically received from database. So that makes all the forms to have a common name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your anchor elements all call your `next()` function without passing any information about which item was selected. You could change that by using `onclick='next(this)'` so that your function gets a reference to the clicked anchor, but it's generally best not to include JS directly inside your html - especially if you're using a library like jQuery which makes it really easy to set up event handlers. (I assume you are either using jQuery already or are open to it given you added the jQuery tag to your question.)

I'd suggesting changing your anchor from:

```
<a href="javascript:next()">
```

...to something like:

```
<a class="selectAddress">
```

And then instead of your `next()` function you can use a jQuery-based click handler as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.selectAddress").click(function() {
       $(this).find("form")
              .prop("action", "checkout3.jsp")
              .submit();
    });    
});
```

That is, bind a click handler to all anchors with that class. Within the handler, `this` will be the particular anchor clicked, so you can use the `.find()` method to select the form that is a descendant of the anchor, then set its `action` property, then submit it. Note that your form has `method="post"` in its html, so there's no need to set this again like you do in your `next()` function.